# How does earthing happen?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-current, charge, potential, conductors

Earthing, as I have been told, is done by inserting a conductor in the ground whilst it is connected to the body whose earthing needs to be done.

But how does the charge get transferred into the ground: what part of the soil is creating the potential difference and what acts as the conductor in the soil?

Comment: Grounding rods are generally driven into moist soil, and that moisture naturally contains dissolved salts which improve its conductivity. A non-corrosive salt like magnesium sulfate may be used to enhance the conductivity in the the vicinity of the rod. Grounding rods in totally dry sandy soil don't work too well...

Answer (score 0):

Earthing doesn't necessarily mean flowing of charges.The point of earthing is --- Earth/Ground is considered of having a zero potential. Moreover, it is a source of infinite charge retrieval and storage. So, a conductor having null Potential will not flow any charge back to the earth.

Comment: What about conductors that have a non-zero potential, that was essentially my question

Comment: For those having non-zero potential, the charges will flow from earth to conductor if the conductor has -ve potential and the opposite case for vice-versa , till the point potential of conductor  =0.
One, more thing, the potential of earth is never changed whatever be the amount of charge flowing.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but how; please read my original post again

Comment: I think you are thinking too much in that.. as such there no"part" which is creating the phenomenon...just think the conductor to be v.very small as compared to the large ground...basically there is so little charge transferred or lost that it doesn't effect the overall charge density of the earth

Answer (score 0):

[image: without earthing case]

**when earthing is done**
[image: earthing case]

The fault current passes through the earth wire, as we know current follows the path which has the least resistance. and earth has infinite capacitance, hence the small amount of charge delivering into the earth didn't make any difference in potential.

Comment: Current does not take the path of least of resistance. It takes all paths. In theory, if current has a choice between a zero resistance path and a finite resistance path, all the current takes the path of the zero resistance. A path with zero resistance however is an idealization

Comment: indeed An electric current is a stream of charged particles, such as electrons or ions, moving through an electrical conductor or space and a stream of particles move in all possible directions , I mean to say that only, the current is the rate of change of charge per unit time. as there are 2 choices available human body and low resistance wire connected to the ground. REGARDS